# reading an image from a file and displaying it using java

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JavaImageIOTest
{

  public JavaImageIOTest()
  {
    try
    {
      // the line that reads the image file
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\ Users \ Public \ Pictures\    Sample Pictures\ Penguins.jpg"));
      // work with the image here ...
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // log the exception
      // re-throw if desired
    }  
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    new ImageIOTest();
  }
```

}

for this im getting path specification errors.....so could u plese suggest me the exact code for reading an image and displaying it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double slashes in the file specification

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg"));
```

Comment: Dah, you beat me! I'll delete my answer :(